# Azure Pipelines DotNetCoreCLI error for not finding the file

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, dotnetcorecli

I am following a youtube tutorial and so far everything was great, tutorial uses Visual studio and I am using vs code

I am totally new to this and this is my first project. I've tried ms build, entering URL, but nothing works

[image: Repository]

```
trigger:
- master

pool: MyComputerAgent

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
  
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '7.0.400'  # Specify the .NET 7 SDK version

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    command: build
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
```

Comment: You're telling it to look for `**/*.sln` in the `NuGetCommand@2` step. Where is the file extension ending in `.sln`? Unrelated: You should add a `.gitignore` and ensure that you never commit `bin` and `obj` directories to version control.

Comment: Could you share with us error message?